# How do I create a new tag?

Tags: support, tags

From time to time, I notice some missing tags that would be useful. How do I add one?

Answer (score 8):

Tags can only be created if you ask a question and tag it with a tag that has not been used on the site previously, otherwise there is no way to "create" a tag.